# SQL table statistics, how to determine which stats to update?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a few tables that add 100k's of rows per day. Some of the statistics get updated, but not all of them. There seem to be 50+ statistics listed. 1/2 were updated a few days ago but some, not since 3 months ago. Should I update these? Why would they not be updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as all Auto Create/Auto Update is on... then the reason the SQL optimizer wouldn't update the statistics is likely because it deems it un-necesarry to generating optimal query plans.

This in turn is probably because the standard usage of your tables doesn't often leverage them in queries (i.e. where clauses, comparisons, joins, etc.)

You CAN manually update the statistics but if SQL isn't keeping them up to date then in your normal course of activity you'll likely notice no improvement.  (as long as Auto Update is on)

On the flip... if you suddenly start running queries on a column that historically wasn't used very often then the optimizer will probably change it's mind and start keeping a closer eye on it.

Back to Auto Update... if it's off, then you're in roll-your-own territory.  Also, if someone went in and manually created a bunch of statistics then these wouldn't be updated by SQL either, unless they became useful while optimizing queries.

[This Books Online article is an excellent source of information.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd535534%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Edited the link to the BOL article.  Towards the bottom it get's into best practices and a discussion of what triggers updates.  Some of the BOL stuff is so, so, this article I think is excellent.